# Show user details using ClickHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of users, how do I click through to the details for each user?

Do I need to do the api call in this component?

Any help much appreciated

Here is my user list:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Users extends Component {

showDetails(){

// navigate to details page

}

render() {
    return (
        <Table responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         {this.props.users.map((user, index) => (
            <tr onClick={showDetails}>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.username}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
            </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
}
}
```

Here my component that gets the users, do I need to:

```
class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {users: []};
  }

getUsers(){ 
 axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
 .then((response) => {
     this.setState({ users: response.data });
 })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
 });
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getUsers();
}

  render() {
      return (<div>

    <Users users={this.state.users} />

  </div>);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to user details page you can use react router like this

```
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";
...
<tr onClick={() => browserHistory.push(`/user-info/${user.id}`)}>
...
```

Then to get info about users you need to use 'redux' so that you load users info to common storage and since be able to recieve it from any component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can I use `react-router` without `redux` for now? Where would I put my api calls?